# Visual studio 15.7.0 xamarin form build error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hello guys i have just update my vs community to the latest version.after the update if i am trying to create a normal `Xamarin.From` application then it's giving me some **error**.

```
Xamari.froms.build.tasks.xamlGtask could not be loaded.
```

I tried to uninstall `xamar.forms` and install it again..but that doesn't help also.

What should i do?

Comment: You can re-install the VS or try fixing from the Web Installer, it might work.

Comment: VS2017 15.x.0 updates are always very buggy.  Be sure to update it.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem next.

Answer (score 1):

- Clean the project
- Close the project
- Delete folders Temp,Prefetch and %temp%
- Open project
- Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Update Xamarin.Forms version in your Xamarin forms solution (PCL,Xamarin iOS project and Xamarin Android). Most of the times    reason for this behavior is your solution contains older xamarin    forms version and Visual Studio contains latest version.